# JQuery action when counter reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, jquery-events

I've created this under construction page: http://psyhealth.ro/

What I need is when that counter reaches 0 to directly open a page. In this case: main.html
I am new to JQuery and don't know how to do that. Please help.

```
$('#countdown').timeTo({
    timeTo: new Date(new Date('Fri Apr 11 2014 19:30:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)')),
    displayDays: 2,
    theme: "black",
    displayCaptions: true,
    fontSize: 40,
    captionSize: 14
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well going through your source and checking out your plugin, I believe this is the way to do it:

```
$('#countdown').timeTo({
    timeTo: new Date(new Date('Fri Apr 11 2014 19:30:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)')),
    displayDays: 2,
    theme: "black",
    displayCaptions: true,
    fontSize: 40,
    captionSize: 14
}, function () {
    window.location = "http://mypage.com";
});
```

Comment: Why don't define the callback in the option?

Comment: @sdespont Sure that's another way to go ! However this just feels a bit more idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://lexxus.github.io/jq-timeTo/

Here is you what you are looking for :

```
$('#countdown').timeTo({
timeTo: new Date(new Date('Fri Apr 11 2014 19:30:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)')),
displayDays: 2,
theme: "black",
displayCaptions: true,
fontSize: 40,
captionSize: 14,
callback : function(){ location.replace("page2.html"); }
});
```

Comment: and replace `alert('Countdown finished');` with `location.replace("page2,html");`

Comment: @mplungjan indeed :o)